# Python Requests, how i perform multiple POST action

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, screen-scraping

I use `python 3.2` and the most recent version of the `Requests` library.  When I perform a first HTTP POST to a login to the endpoint, i log in successfully. Now I want to post some data after login. When I a perform 2nd post i got a valid answer (`200 OK`), but the response redirect URL of the 2nd post action is `example.com/index`. Normally it should be `example.com/my-account`, but nothing changes when i refresh the browser to see that.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import requests
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from furl import furl
#get user compenent
mail="thoryn.hiroshi@lcelandic.com"
password="333"
url = 'https://example.com/login.php'

#make the requests in one session
with requests.session() as client:
# Retrieve the CSRF(sid) token first
tree = etree.HTML(client.get(url).content)
csrf = tree.xpath('//input[@name="_sid"]/@value')[0]

#form data
formData = dict(_sid=csrf, email=mail,pwd=password,process="login")

#use same session client
r = client.post(url, data=formData)
idurl=r.url
print( r.request.headers)
g=client.get(idurl)

# this for scrape site html data, i guess isn't matter with requests problem
soup = BeautifulSoup(g.text, 'html.parser')
adispo=soup.find_all('a', attrs={"class":"dispo"})
i=0
datalist=[]

for i in range(0,len(adispo)):
    linkajax=adispo[i]['onclick']
    parsedlink= linkajax[30:247]
    temp=furl(parsedlink)
    data={
        "timestamp":temp.args['timestamp'],
        "skey":temp.args['skey'],
        "id":temp.args['fg_id'],
        "time":temp.args['result']
    }
    datalist.append(data)

# print(rdvlist,len(rdvlist))
getdata=datalist[0]
posturl='https://example.com/action.php'
datapayload={
    "data name":"data"
}

secondpost=client.post(posturl,data=datapayload)
print(secondpost.reason, secondpost.url)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to be a reusable program for validating multiple request responses you're going to need to structure this to handle objects.  Wrap this into three functions, one to send HTTP requests, one to handle the HTTP response and one to scrape attributes off the HTTP response DOM.  Then you can wrap functions into a loop and execute the main script multiple times off a list of URL's.

Here's a good reference to get started with: https://eliasdorneles.github.io/2014/08/30/web-scraping-with-scrapy---first-steps.html

Comment: i should use scrapy module ?

Comment: @MomoSetti
It will help accomplish what you're trying to do, yes.